# Run tcsh with arbitrary startup script

Tags: shell, tcsh

I want to create a new instance of `tcsh` and source an arbitrary script, all in one step.  The problem is that when I use the `-c` option, the shell instance closes as soon as the script is complete.  So, in the following **trivial example** the `pushd` command completes successfully but then the shell exits:

```
tcsh -c "pushd ~/some/directory/of/interest"
```

**How can I source a script which modifies the environment and then work interactively within that environment?** This is most useful when used in conjunction with programs like `ssh` or `screen`, as in the following:

```
ssh -t user@host 'tcsh -c "source ~/test_environment.csh"'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our solution will involve two steps.

1. Pass Environment variable containing path to script you want to source to new `tcsh` instance.
2. Have `tcsh` source the script pointed at by this environment variable

---

For step 1 `ssh` will run the command you specify in your default shell (the one in the destination server's `/etc/passwd`) so I'll give you several solutions for this.

- If destination shell is `sh`/`bash`: Connect to ssh server with command: `ssh -t user@host
  'export SOURCESCRIPT=/tmp/tmp.sh; exec /usr/bin/tcsh'`
- If destination shell is `csh`/`tcsh`: Connect to ssh server with command: `ssh -t
  user@host 'setenv SOURCESCRIPT /tmp/tmp.sh; exec /usr/bin/tcsh'`
- If you can modify the destination's ssh server config, add/modify `AcceptEnv` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow `SOURCESCRIPT` environment variable to be passed (e.g. `AcceptEnv SOURCESCRIPT`), set `SOURCESCRIPT` in local environment and connect with command: `ssh -t -o SendEnv=SOURCESCRIPT user@host 'exec /usr/bin/tcsh'`

---

For step 2, we modify `~/.tcshrc` to add the following:

```
if $?SOURCESCRIPT then
    source $SOURCESCRIPT
endif
```

Comment: This is a very nice, straight-forward workaround!  It requires modifying the user's `~/.tcshrc` beforehand, but that is not a problem in my scenario.

Comment: Glad to hear it was successful! Thanks for catching the error, fixed that equal sign.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you use the '-m' option for tcsh to load a startup script?  I just read the man page and thought that you might be able to make the '~/.tcshrc' file a symlink to another script.  In case there's something screwey going on with the commands, maybe you could try the '-e' or '-m' options.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Or maybe you could use the '-i' option for interactive in conjunction with the '-c' option :)

Comment: `~/.tcshrc` is my startup script, so I can't just replace it with a symlink.  I am looking for a way to optionally run an **alternate** startup script.